# Why we can't make an analogous definition for complex convex sets as in the real case?

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

For real case we have the following definition:

> **Def. 1** $~~$ Let $K$ a subset of a real vector space $V$. We say that $K$ is convex when $\theta x + (1-\theta)y\in K$ whenever $x,y\in K$ and $\theta \in [0,1]$.

Why we cannot have an analogous definition for complex vector spaces?

We can't ask for $\theta\in \Bbb C$ with $|\theta| \leq 1$ because this would be similar to ask for $\theta \in [-1, 1]$ in the real case, and this take more points than we want. But if we simply don't change the requirement $\theta \in [0,1]$ in Def. 1, why this would be a bad definition? That is, why is

> **Def. 2** $~~$ Let $K$ a subset of a *complex* vector space $V$. We say that $K$ is convex when $\theta x + (1-\theta)y\in K$ whenever $x,y\in K$ and $\theta \in [0,1]$.

a bad definition?

Other question. There exists a simple definition for convex complex functions as in the real case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you don't need.

Any complex vector space is automatically also a real vector space. So the definition 2 you propose is actually just definition 1.

Comment: Look at the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_convexity Why it is that way? Other question. There exists a simple definition for convex complex functions as in the real case? (Just added this question in the body)

Comment: @Filburt That's a different definition. Convex sets are studied a lot in functional analysis, and can be defined in any real or complex vector space using definition 1 in your post. There are few really important Theorems involving compactness (and/or weak compactness) and closeness of convex sets in Banach spaces or in locally convex topological vector space. In all these cases, the point is that one doesn't need to worry about the case when the field is $\mathbb C$, as the space is automatically a real vector space in that case.

Comment: @Filburt The point I am trying to make is that there is no difference between Def 2 and Def 1.